# Classic geometry problem with algebra

Tags: geometry

> Given right $\triangle ABC$ such that $\angle ACB=90^\circ$ with height $CH$. If the length of all three side of the triangle are integer and $BH=29^3$ then find $\cos \angle ABC$

I have an incomplete solution that using Wolfram alpha to help. First let $AB=c$, $BC=a$, $AC=b$ so we have $a^2=29^3c$. That mean I could pick $a=29^2n$, $c=29n^2$ for some integer $n$ but I can't solve for anything useful at all. But as for $b^2=(c-29^3)c$, I could get $a=29^2×421$, $b=60×29×421$ $c=29×421^2$ ( by Wolfram alpha ). So then I could solve for $\cos \angle ABC=\frac{29}{421}$. I wonder if there is any other approach to this without involving calculator or heavy algebra at all. And if you know the good way to solve $b^2=(c-29^3)c$ please let me know too ( sorry for asking two questions ). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something useful from letting $a=29^2 n$ and $c= 29n^2$. We have:

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \leadsto 29^4 n^2 + b^2 = 29^2n^4$$

Since $b$ is an integer, it must be of the form $29nk$. Then we have:

$$29^4 n^2 + 29^2 n^2 k^2 = 29^2n^4 \leadsto 29^2 + k^2 = n^2$$

and so $(29,k,n)$ forms a Pythagorean triple. We know that Pythagorean triples are of the form:

$$(p^2-q^2, 2pq, p^2+q^2)$$

so we have $29 = p^2-q^2 = (p+q)(p-q)$. Since $29$ is prime, $p+q=29$ and $p-q=1$. Thus $$p=15, q=14, k = 2pq = 420, n = p^2 + q^2 = 421$$

Therefore $$\cos\angle ABC = \frac ac = \frac {29^2 n }{29n^2} = \frac{29}n = \frac {29}{421}$$

Comment: I totally forgot about The Pythagorean triples!. Thanks for the solution